# Generating pdf from stored items in session

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate pdf with php and elements which I take from session. Currently the pdf is generated but it doesn't matter how many items i have it always showing me only 1.. first item. I think that something with my query is wrong but can't find what. Here is the script I have so far.

```
$files = $_SESSION['itemid'];

if(is_array($files)) {
   foreach($files as $file) {

    $sql = "SELECT upload_id, upload_title, upload_description FROM document_upload WHERE upload_id = :id"; 
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(":id", $file);
    $result->execute();                 

    $resArray = $result->fetchAll();
    foreach ( $resArray as $res )
    {

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();    
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',18);
        $pdf->Cell(0,6,'Selected',0,1,'C');

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
        $pdf->Ln();
        $pdf->Cell(20,12,$res['upload_id'],1);
        $pdf->Cell(50,12,$res['upload_title'],1);
        $pdf->Cell(120,12,$res['upload_description'],1);

        $pdf->Output();
    }
   }      
}
```

When I `print_r($files);` I see `Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 12 [2] => 14 )`
but when I `print_r($file);` inside the foreach I see only `11`.

I'm using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: yes, well the foreach iterated through each array key, so um that's to be expected

Comment: Thank's @Dagon but I still don't get it.

Comment: Move your $pdf = new FPDF(); out of the loop, also in the first loop itself you are outputting `$pdf->Output();`. so move that too out of loop.

Comment: Still same. Just first element.

Comment: Thank's to both of you. I have updated my question with the solution.

Comment: please post the answer as an answer  not in the question, thanks

Comment: You're right. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have put `$pdf = new FPDF();` and `$pdf->Output();` inside the loop. When I moved them outside everything works perfectly.

Here is complete and working solution:

```
if(is_array($files)) 
{
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',18);
    $pdf->Cell(0,6,'Selected',0,1,'C');

    foreach($files as $file) 
    {

         $sql = "SELECT upload_id, upload_title, upload_description FROM document_upload WHERE upload_id = :id"; 
         $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
         $result->bindParam(":id", $file);
         $result->execute();                 

         $resArray = $result->fetchAll();

         foreach ( $resArray as $res )
         {
              $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
              $pdf->Ln();   

              $pdf->Cell(20,12,$res['upload_id'],1);
              $pdf->Cell(50,12,$res['upload_title'],1);
              $pdf->Cell(120,12,$res['upload_description'],1);
         }
    }     
    $pdf->Output();  
}
```